# Split order in two if specific product is in cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to split order into two orders if customer tries to buy one normal product and one magazine subscription. Is that possible to achieve in Prestashop admin panel or do I have to override some controllers/classes?

I cannot use multiple warehouses to handle the situation as I have external stock management and don't want to mess things up.

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.1.2.

Comment: The way I did it was to create a module that doesn't allow mixing subscription and normal products in cart. If you really wanted to split orders you'd have to rewrite the whole `validateOrder()` method in `PaymentModule` class and given that the method is complex and written in 800+ lines you'll be better off with the not mixing items in cart solution.

Comment: @TheDrot unfortunately I cannot prevent customers from mixing these two types of products. Currently I'm trying to refactor the `validateOrder()` method so it's easier to grasp, but I would love to find some easier way to split orders.

Comment: The problem is that there is no other way to do it than refactoring that method... at least not to my knowledge since everything that has to do with order validation and generation is inside that method.

Comment: If you map two products with 2 different shipping, the order automatically gets divided into two.

Comment: @Nimish how to do that?

Comment: Create product 1> Go to shipping tab > Choose shipping 1 for product 1.
Create product 2> Go to shipping tab > Choose shipping 2 for product 2.

Comment: @Nimish this is exactly what I did but then it only shows shipping for the product added last to the cart. It's PS 1.7 and they changed a lot in order process compared to 1.6